# PHP - How to update/delete contact (google People) With PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-people-api

for 3 days i'm frustated because google not have tutorial for php.
(sorry for my bad english)

i got an error while updating names :

```
$client=client_google();
$google_id="people/c3062123412341234";

if ($client->getAccessToken() == "") return null;

$people_service = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);
$person = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Person();

if($tipenya == "Cancel"){
    $name = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Name();
    $name->SetFamilyName("Keluarga Cemara");
    $name->SetGivenName("Tampan");
    $person->setNames($name);

       $profile = $people_service->people->get(
          $google_id, 
          array('personFields' => 'metadata'));

    $etag = $profile->etag;
    $person->setEtag($etag);
    $person->setResourceName($google_id);

       if($google_id !=''){
       //$people_service->people->updatePersonField("names");
       $people_service->people->updateContact($google_id,$person);
        }

    }else if($tipenya=="Delete"){
       if($google_id !=''){
       $person->setResourceName($google_id);
       $people_service->people->deleteContact($person);
       }

    }
```

Error when i execute:

> exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
>         "error": {
>       "code": 400,
>       "message": "updatePersonFields mask is required. Please specify one or more valid paths. Valid paths are documented at https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/update.",
>       "errors": [
>         {
>           "message": "updatePersonFields mask is required. Please specify one or more valid paths. Valid paths are documented at https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/update.",
>           "domain": "global",
>           "reason": "badRequest"
>         }
>       ],
>       "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"  }}'

Comment: Did you try asking in the Google forums? I would assume that is the best place to gather relevant information about Google products.

Comment: The link in the Errormessage is not working. Try this: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the parameter `updatePersonFields`. Seems like the parameters are passed as the last argument by looking at the read examples in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/read-people). It probably should look something like:

```
$params = array('updatePersonFields' => 'names,emailAddresses');
$people_service->people->updateContact($google_id,$person,$params);
```

I haven't tested the above, so that might not be the exact syntax.